# Text only carousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am unable to have a carousel with only text **without any img**. The text seems to be colliding with the controls. Every example I've found uses the `<img>`. I have tried to use `d-flex` class, block and even the `carousel-caption`. Nothing has worked so far.

```
<div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <p>lorem ipsum (imagine longer text)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <p>lorem ipsum (imagine longer text)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try adding some padding on `.carousel-inner`?

Comment: Adding `padding-left` about 200px and `padding-bottom` about 50px somewhat works but it does not look very well with the carousel controls. I can obviously try to position them, too. However, it feels that there should be a clearer way to do it.

Comment: I found one working solution for me [here](http://techfunda.com/howto/1004/sliding-text-carousel)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the `carousel-controls` are designed to overlay the content, whether it's text or images. It would seem that `text-center` would be a good option to center the text of each item.

However, as of BS alpha 6, the `.carousel-item` is `display:flex;` which limits some of the positioning you can do with the contents of `carousel-item`. There is an open issue for this:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21611

As a workaround, you could use `text-center` and override `display:block` for the active carousel item:

```
 <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
       <p>lorem ipsum (imagine longer text)</p>
 </div>

.carousel-item.active {
    display:block;
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/OJHdvdXimm

---

Also see: [Vertically center text in Bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914872/vertically-center-text-in-bootstrap-carousel/45918546#45918546)

Comment: I saw the issue but I somehow got the feeling that it wasn't related. `display: block` definitely helps. I tried to add 100px left and right padding. That fits the text well between the controls, but the animation is funky.

Comment: Is there a way to get the arrows displaying with this?

Comment: The arrows are displaying with it.

Answer (score 0):

I added `px-5` everywhere (in your case in `p`). I needed space around and also added a class to it that gave it a margin of 20px. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the container object

```
    <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-inner text-center text-white m-auto" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
                    <div class="user_text mb-3">
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>
                                Blah
                            </strong><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">

                    <div class="user_text mb-3">
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>
                                Blah Blah

                            </strong><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"></div>
```

To:

```
<div class="carousel-caption"></div>

 .slider-wrap {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators {
   margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

.carousel-text {
   margin: 1rem;
}

.carousel-caption {
   margin: auto!important;
   position: initial!important;
   padding-right: 8rem;
   padding-left: 8rem;
}
```