# Vertically center text in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have trouble creating a carousel in Bootstrap 4 with text centered both horizontally and vertically.

I have created the [bootply](https://www.codeply.com/go/UQT1ynX5XW) with a carousel, but the text is just in the upper left corner instead of in the middle of the screen.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h1>Text 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h1>Text 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h1>Text 3</h1>
    </div>´
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap 4 utility classes (**no additional CSS** is needed)...

https://www.codeply.com/go/ORkdymGWzM

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <h1>Text 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <h1>Text 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <h1>Text 3</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS for `h1` into the following:

```
.carousel-item h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you are missing this:

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
```

Before the `<h1>Text 1</h1>`
So it's like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h1>Text 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then the text will be in the bottom part of the screen instead of vertically centered

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279865/how-to-vertically-center-a-bootstrap-carousel-caption

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` display along with `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.carousel-item {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-item h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The key here is `vertical-align: middle;`  which works only if a div is a table.

Regarding the horizontal alignment, the `text-align: center;` goes to `.carousel-item`. I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

use the container. this worked for me.

```
    <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-inner text-center text-white m-auto" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
                    <div class="user_text mb-3">
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>
                                Blah
                            </strong><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">

                    <div class="user_text mb-3">
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <strong>
                                Blah Blah

                            </strong><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
    </div>
```